# Custom jQuery wordpress nav - showing grandchild with child?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

My company has a custom build wordpress child theme that uses a small jquery script to display the sub nav, then fades out after a second or two. Currently it will only display the sub nav listed horizontally, but I will be transitioning it into a more traditional nav that allows for a tertiary menu.

You can see our current nav [here](http://www.gwca.org)

I have successfully transitioned my css to list vertically on my test site, but the jQuery script is incorrectly showing the tertiary nav (grandchildren) at the same time as the sub-nav (children) when the main-nav's parent is hovered.

Anyone know what I need to change/add to this script to display the grandchildren only once the designated child has been hovered?

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var lastopen = null;
            var timeout = null;

            jQuery("#access ul li ul").show();
            jQuery("#access ul li ul li").hide();

            function showmenu(element)
            {
                element.css("background","url('/var/www/wp-content/themes/GreatWall/images/arrow.png') no-repeat bottom");
                var children = element.find("ul li");
                children.show();
            }

            function hidemenu(element, fade)
            {
                element.css("background","transparent");
                var children = element.find("ul li");
                fade = typeof(fade) != 'undefined' ? fade : false;
                if(fade)
                {
                    children.fadeOut(300);
                }
                else
                {
                    children.hide();
                }
            }

            jQuery("#access ul li").each(function(i,v){
            jQuery(v).mouseover(function(e){if(timeout != null){clearTimeout(timeout); timeout = null;} if(lastopen != null){hidemenu(lastopen);} lastopen = jQuery(this); showmenu(lastopen);});
            jQuery(v).mouseout(function(e){if(timeout != null){clearTimeout(timeout); timeout = null;} timeout=setTimeout(function(){hidemenu(lastopen, true); lastopen = null;},1500);});
            });

            //jQuery("#access ul li ul").css("display", "block");
            //jQuery("#access ul li").each(function(i,v){var width = 0; jQuery(v).find("ul li").each(function(ii,vv){width += jQuery(vv).width();}); var mid = jQuery(v).position().left+jQuery(v).width()/2-width/2; jQuery(v).find("ul li:first").css("margin-left", Math.min(Math.max(0, mid), 940-width));});
            //jQuery("#access ul li").each(function(i,v){var width = 0; jQuery(v).find("ul li").each(function(ii,vv){width += jQuery(vv).width();}); var mid = jQuery(v).position().left; jQuery(v).find("ul li:first").css("margin-left", Math.min(Math.max(0, mid), 940-width));});
            //jQuery("#access ul li ul").css("display", "none");
        });

        </script>
```

and here is the child theme's css for the navigation:

```
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: none;
}  

ul#menu-nav li a:hover{
    background:transparent;
}

#access{
    background:#FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    -moz-box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#081B39;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #081B39 48%, #183563 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #081B39 48%, #183563 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #081B39 48%, #183563 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #081B39 48%, #183563 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #081B39 48%, #183563 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.48, #081B39),
    color-stop(1, #183563));
    -moz-box-shadow:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}

#access ul{
    margin:0;
}

#access li{
    position:relative;
}

#access div{
    margin:0;
}

#access a{
    color:white;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:0 12px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#access li:hover > a, #access a:focus{
    background:none;
    color:#4bb96a;
}

#menu-nav li.current-menu-item a{
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#4bb96a;
}

#access .current_page_item > a, #access .current_page_ancestor > a {
    font-weight:normal;
}





/*-------------------------------------  SUB-NAV STYLING  -----------------------------------------------------*/

/*li#menu-item-185 ul.sub-menu > :first-child{
    margin-left:20px;
}*/

ul.sub-menu{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

/*ul#menu-nav li a:hover{
    background:url(images/arrow.png) no-repeat bottom;
}*/

ul#menu-nav li#menu-item-144 > a:hover, ul#menu-nav li:hover#menu-item-144 > a{
    background:none;
}

.sub-menu li{
    display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a{
    color:#FFF !important;
}

ul.sub-menu li.current_page_item a{
    color:#FFF !important;
    font-style:italic !important;
}

#access ul ul{
top:38px;

    background:#081B39;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #081B39 48%, #183563 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #081B39 48%, #183563 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #081B39 48%, #183563 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #081B39 48%, #183563 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #081B39 48%, #183563 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.48, #081B39),
    color-stop(1, #183563));
    -moz-box-shadow:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}

#access ul ul a {
    border-bottom:none;
    color:#FFF;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    text-align:left;
    background:transparent;

    font-size: 12px;
}

#access ul ul :hover > a {
    background:transparent;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#4bb96a !important;
}
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your children are just the li's of any direct descendants (children) of the current element.  So in jquery long form, your `var children` query in `showmenu` that would be: `var children = element.children('ul').children('li')`  This should get you what you want -- or at least get you on the path!  The query you had was finding all descendants, not just direct descendants, of the current element, which is why your third-level menu items were being shown.

If you can post the live example somewhere (jsfiddle, or a live demo link) then it'll be easier to give you more support.  But I think this should do it.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle, I put grandchildren links for each link under 'about' any idea what needs to be added to now display after child has been hovered?

http://jsfiddle.net/CSwgQ/1/

Comment: http://nederdev.nl/node/51 I'm a fan of suckerfish / son of suckerfish technique.  Straight forward.  But here's my updated version of your script: http://jsfiddle.net/CSwgQ/4/ - you only want to call hidemenu on other siblings at the current level you're at.  So the whole concept of 'lastopen' is only really important for the final hover when you're fading out.